# Which characters are unique to which version?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

While I know that the playable characters from *Birthright* are, for the most part, not playable in *Conquest*, what about *Revelations*? Do you simply get all the characters from both sides in *Revelations* or are some characters only available in one of the three versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nearly every character in both Birthright and Conquest are playable in Revelations, the only exceptions being Izana, who is gained by upgrading your My Castle hot springs to level 3 after a certain point in the game ([you can check his wiki page for spoilers on when specifically](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Izana)) and certain capturable characters that are unique to the Birthright and Conquest paths, which are noted [here](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Capture#Capturable_Boss_Units). For a full list of characters in the game, including NPCs featured in the game, capturable boss characters, and children, you can look [here](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_characters_in_Fire_Emblem_Fates). It also shows which ones are unique to Birthright and Conquest for those interested.